# Javascript: Reference Variable

Tags: javascript

```
    var foo = {
    _name: 'John',
    getIdentity: function (){
        return this._name;
    }
};

var stoleIdentity = foo.getIdentity;

console.log(stoleIdentity());
console.log(foo.getIdentity());
```

Hi, may I know, is there any other implementation for me to achieve the same result as the code above?

And why I cannot get the result for the `stoleIdentity`?

Answer (score 3):

`this` in JavaScript gets defined by very specific circumstances; the one we're interested in is in a "method call", which looks like this:

```
receiver.method(argument_list...)
```

If the receiver is not mentioned in the function call, it is a plain function call, not a method call, and `this` does not get set.

Thus, `foo.getIdentity()` is a method call, which sets `this` to `foo`, and `this._name` gets evaluated as `foo._name`; `stoleIdentity()` is a plain function call, which does not change `this`, and `this._name` will likely access `window._name`, unless `this` got changed some other way in the meantime.

You can bind the receiver to a function value using `Function.prototype.bind` (one of the other ways to change `this`). So if you use this line instead, your code will work:

```
var stoleIdentity = foo.getIdentity.bind(foo);
```

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. It helped me understand clearly.

Answer (score 0):

When you assigned foo.getIdentity to stoleIdentity, the this was changed. You can log this to check it out.

Use this bind to bind this to stoleIdentity to let it work.

```html
var foo = {
    _name: 'John',
    getIdentity: function (){
        return this._name;
    }
};

var stoleIdentity = foo.getIdentity.bind(foo);

console.log(stoleIdentity());
console.log(foo.getIdentity());
```